# SAME PARQUET FILE different float values read when using AzureML Dataset vs Directly Getting From Azure Storage using Bytestream

Tags: pandas, dataframe, azure, parquet, azure-machine-learning-service

A little background, we are exploring a dataset given by a 3rd party vendor, which they've exposed to us using their SNOWFLAKE instance. What I did then was I exported this dataset into our Azure Blob Storage(s) as parquet files then created an AzureML dataset that encapsulates the parquet files that are stored in our BLOB CONTAINERS.

As I was exploring the data, I raised to them that I saw erroneous data with their longitude and latitude data which they denied. I then sent screenshots of the erroneous data, and when we queried the same data using SNOWFLAKE that I am raising as erroneous, the values were indeed correct!

I was baffled, and upon investigation, I narrowed it down to AzureML dataset somewhat gives INCORRECT data VERSUS if you directly read the parquet file / blob via stream into a pandas dataframe.

Also, all text data were identical, but when it came to FLOAT values, the incorrect values are manifesting.

I checked the datatypes when defining the schema of the AzureML dataset, and they are correct

[image]

Honestly, Im stomped. Any ideas or anyone encountered this issue and can explain to me what is happening? Thank you

### **SCREENSHOTS BELOW**

Here is when read using the AzureML dataset

[image: Here is when read using the AzureML dataset]

---

Here is the same file, same record, read directly from blob storage using bytestream

[image: Here is the same file, same record, read directly from blob storage using bytestream]

Downloaded the parquet file to my local machine and viewed it

---

[image: Downloaded the parquet file to my local machine and viewed it]

---